# echoing data From mySQL when table column joined twice

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to echo both the employee name and manager name

#### SQL QUERY:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `form` 
INNER JOIN `emp` AS employee
ON `form`.emp_ID = employee.emp_ID
INNER JOIN `emp` AS manager
ON `form`.manager_ID = manager.emp_ID
```

#### ECHO:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo $row['emp_name']; 
}
```

Always outputs the managers name.

have tried the following:

```
$row['employee.emp_name']
$row['employee']['emp_name']
```

which all don't work.

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the columns have the same name, their values will overlap when retrieving by `fetch_assoc()`. You can either use `fetch_array()` and reference the columns by numeric index (not recommended with `SELECT *`, since you can't easily guarantee the order of columns), or you will have to list the column names explicitly and alias them. For example:

```
SELECT emp.emp_name emp_emp_name, manager.emp_name manager_emp_name, ...
```

This would give you separate distinctly named fields in the result, that you could then access from what `fetch_assoc()` returns.